# Can't display selectors content in Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I'm trying to extract a table from a website, and wanted to get all the columns first. After the request is made, I load the html into cheerio, but when I try to display the selector content, nothing appears on the console. What is confusing me is when I try the same selector directly on to the page console, it works and shows me all of them.

Here is the [url](https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking) I'm scraping.

Here is the cheerio selector I'm using to return the columns. The content I want is on the tag th with the class 'sorting'.

```
$('.sorting').each(function (index, element) {
                const $element = $(element);
                console.log($element.text());
            });
```

And here is the full code.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const fundsExplorerUrl = 'https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking';

request(fundsExplorerUrl,
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(body);

            $('.sorting').each(function (index, element) {
                const $element = $(element);
                console.log($element.text());
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Sorting class is added by js after loaded, you can view source to check it, no class `sorting` in raw html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the raw HTML, there is no class called `sorting` because javascript is dynamically adding this class to dom so in this specific case by using following code you can gather the content of all `th` tags embedded in the `thead` tag of `table` tag.

```js
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking';

async function crawl() {
    const rawHtml = await request(url);
    const $ = cheerio.load(rawHtml);

    $('table thead tr th')
        .each( (index, element) => {
        console.log($(element).text());
    })
}

crawl();
```